# How to get users information according to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables with name = Users, Gallaries and UserLikes.

1. 'Users' table contains all the information regarding a user.
2. 'Gallaries' table contains whole the images types, urls uploaded by all the users. In which each user has more than 1 image.
3. 'UserLikes' table contains the information about which user is liked by which user.

Users:

```
userId    name     emailId             status
  1       Aman     aman@gmail.com        1
  2       deep     deep@gmail.com        1
  3       singh    singh@gmail.com       1
```

Gallaries:

```
id       imageUrl      userId     type         createdOn
1       www.url.com     1         png          125120560
2       www.url1.com    1         png          115220533
```

UserLikes:

```
id      UserLikedBy       UserLiked        createdOn
1           1                2             120603200
2           1                3             126566233
3           2                1             120603200
```

What I want to get:

- I want all users (except me) that I have not liked yet

  +
- I want all the imageUrls of that users to whom I have not liked yet.

I also managed all image urls with comma separated.

My query is:

```
select usr.*, 
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Media_url FROM Galleries gallery
       WHERE usr.userId = gallery.userId FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') as media_url 

       from Users usr
       left Join (
            select UserLiked, UserLikedBy, Id from UserLikes where UserLiked = 1
       ) us ON us.UserLiked <> usr.userId
       where usr.userId <> 1
```

Comment: userid is confusing in your Users table

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having the above table data. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: This is not a code writing service but we are very happy to help you with any problems you may be having when writing your own code.

Comment: Updated with my own query

Comment: Thank you for your code. What problems are you having? Does it produce the expected result? What is the expected result?

Comment: I am getting those users also that I did't liked yet and getting duplicate records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following joins to get the desired result

```
declare @myID int = 1

select u.*, 
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Media_url FROM Galleries gallery
       WHERE u.userId = gallery.userId FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') as media_url 

from UserLikes ul
right join Users u on u.userId  = ul.UserLiked and ul.UserLikedBy = @myID

where ul.id is null and u.userId <> @myID
order by u.userId
```

Comment: Thanks dear. This is what I was looking for. Here I cant understand about 'where ul.id is null'

Comment: This helps you find the Users you have not liked. If the UserLikes entry on the right join is null, it means you have not liked that user. You can use whichever column you want for the null check. It could be for example  'where ul.createdOn is null'

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is to perform an antijoin on a map table. Use join on not exists:

```
select 
    target.userId as [My ID]
    ,others.userId as [Not Liked ID]
    ,urltable.imageUrls as [Not Liked URLs]
from Users target
inner join Users others on not exists
(
    select 1
    from UserLikes l
    where l.UserLikedBy=target.userId
    and l.UserLiked=others.userId
)
cross apply(select
    STUFF(  ( 
            select ',' + imageUrl
            from Gallaries g
            where g.userId=others.userId
            order by g.id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1, '') as imageUrls
) as urltable
```